# Image Formation in plane mirror

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

1. I just read that in image formation by plane mirror the rays can't go above the height of the object and below principal? Whereas in concave/convex mirror the light ray can go above/below . Why is it so?
2. Why does the intersection of reflected rays forms the image of that object ?